# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND uploading files bigger than 500Mb

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-upload, filereader, form-data

I have a problem uploading files bigger than 500Mb.

I created a plunker file with error code: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/vKHNkUuVX1RrMcZ6Ezhc?p=preview

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/uploadFile");
request.send(formData);

request.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    console.log(evt.loaded / evt.total);
  } else {
    console.log('Undefined percent...');
  }
}, false);
request.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
  console.error(evt);
}, false);
request.addEventListener("error", function(evt) {
  console.error(evt);
}, false);
```

To reproduce the error:

1. Open Chrome with link of plunker file.
2. Open inspector console (F12).
3. Upload file with size between 300Mb and 500Mb.
4. Server response with error, but the code try to upload the file selected.
5. Upload file bigger than 200Mb.
6. Get an **net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND** from client code, the call not arrive to server.

Best regards and thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the server configuration to see if it has a upper limit to file size uploads? (ref. 4) What is the error message the server gives btw?

Comment: No exist the server in plunker example, the error is normal (ref. 4). In my real code I have 1Gb size of limit on server side and I have the same problem when I send I send files bigger than 500Mb (ref. 6). Thanks.

Comment: Try another browser. Chrome throw ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND that is not an error in Javascript.